# is there a way of looping pattern action pair in lex program?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I was wondering if there is a means of looping in rules section of a lex program, where i can iterate both pattern and action.

something like this:

```
%{
  char *pattern[] = {a,b,c,d,e}
%}

%%
 for(i=0,i<5,i++){
   (pattern[1]){action[i]}
 }
%%

//Some functions
```

Is it possible to make such kind of iteration?

I am in looking for a way to write a lex progam that can identify all C language keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how looping will help you solve this problem. (F)lex already loops, repeatedly finding a token until some action returns (or EOF is reached and the default EOF action returns).

To identify keywords, just write the keywords out as patterns:

```
%{
  int keywords = 0;
%}   
%option noyywrap
%%
 /* List of keywords taken from http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.1 */
auto                    { ++keywords; }
break                   { ++keywords; }
case                    { ++keywords; }
char                    { ++keywords; }
const                   { ++keywords; }
continue                { ++keywords; }
default                 { ++keywords; }
do                      { ++keywords; }
 /* Etc. */
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*                ; /* Ignore other identifiers */
\.?[[:digit:]]([[:alnum:].]|[EePp][+-])* ; /* And pp-numbers */
 /* The next one matches too much; it will cause keywords inside comments
  * and quoted strings to be accepted. So you still have some work to do. */
[^[:alnum:]]+                            ; /* And everything else */

%%
int main(void) {
  yylex();
  printf("%d keywords found.\n", keywords);
  return 0;
}
```

If you need to distinguish between the keywords, you'll need to do something more sophisticated. But a good text editor should let you convert the list of keywords into any simple repeated action, such as

```
auto     { return TOKEN_auto; }
```

Comment: I have done it like you did, the so is i was looking a way of simplifying the program by having an array of all C keywords and iterating through each value.

Comment: @kee: no. Flex *compiles* the scanner. You can't modify the rules at runtime.